# Compute a cardinality using Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I look for computing this cardinality:
$$N(q)=\#\{n \in \mathbb{N} \ | \ \gcd(n^2+1, \prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ \text{p prime}}}p)=1 , \ \ n^2+1 \leqslant \prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ \text{p prime}}}p \},$$
Using **Chinese remainder theorem**.

First, for $p$ odd prime and $m\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the number of solutions of the equation $m^2 + 1 = 0 \pmod p$ is :
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 0 & \text{ if } p = 3 \pmod 4 \\ 2 & \text{ if } p = 1 \pmod 4 \end{array} \right.$$

Using **Chinese remainder theorem** and **fundamental counting principle** i get this result:
$$N(q) = \bigg(\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 3[4] \\ \text{p prime}}}p \bigg)\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 1[4] \\ \text{p prime}}}(p-2) \tag{1}$$
Formula $(1)$ is not correct when i check $N(q)$ numerically.

The true values are :
$$N(7)=5, \ N(11)=15, \ N(13)=45 , \ N(17)=161, \ N(19)=698, \cdots$$

**Question:** Why my formula $(1)$ is not correct !? and what is the correct formula ?

Many thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** Numerically it's very likely that:
$$N(q) \approx \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\displaystyle \prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ \text{p prime}}}p }} \, \bigg(\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 3[4] \\ \text{p prime}}}p \bigg)\prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ p \equiv 1[4] \\ \text{p prime}}}(p-2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re counting the set with the restriction $n\le\prod_{p\le q}p$ rather than $n^2+1\le\prod_{p\le q}p$.

The estimate in your last line makes sense if we think of the elements as uniformly randomly distributed, since $N(q)$ counts approximately a proportion $\left(\prod_{p\le q}p\right)^{-\frac12}$ of the elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we look forcounting the number of $b$ verifying $\displaystyle \gcd(b, \prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ \text{p prime}}}p)=1$ with $b=n^2+1$ and $b \leqslant \displaystyle \prod_{\substack{p \leqslant q \\ \text{p prime}}}p$

Comment: @LAGRIDA: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. That's just a reformulation of the conditions in the question.

Comment: i check your answer and you have right, i need to compute for all $n\le\prod_{p\le q}p$